# How can I redirect to an exact URL with Serenity + cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm making automation test and in one step I want to redirect to an exact page but not through a button or some UI action, just like when you write an URL in the explorer. I'm using `serenity.conf` and not `Driver myDriver = new Driver();`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand truly;

This should be your page class with `@DefaultUrl` annotation;

```
@DefaultUrl("https://google.com ")
public class GoogleHomePage extends PageObject {

   // Some Code 
}
```

After that you can call that like;

```
public class NavigateTo {

    GoogleHomePage googleHomePage;

    @Step("Open google homepage")
    public void googleHomePage() {

        googleHomePage.open();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@NameUrls(
         {
           @NameUrl(name = "OrangeHRM_Page", url = "/index.php/auth/{1}")
         }
)

public class HomePage extends PageObject{

}


public class NavigatePage extends PageObject{
HomePage homePage;

@Steps("Open Home Page")
public void goToHomePage(){
     //with parameter will helpful to redirect to specific page mentioned
    homePage.open("OrangeHRM_Page", withParameters("requestPasswordResetCode"));
}
}
```

In the **serenity.properties** file:

```
webdriver.driver = chrome
webdriver.base.url = https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/
```